# creating a separate file to connect to mysql with php

Tags: php, database

I want to use a single file for my php application to connect to a database when the user register for the first time or login in

what is the code is it same as below is good:

```
$username="root";
$password="root";
$database="test";



    function Save($name)
    {
        global $username;
        global $password;
        global $database;

        $link = mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
        $query = "INSERT INTO test (name)" .
                 "VALUES ('" . $name . "')";
        mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();
    }
```

Also, how can i do the require for that file? it is located in the root of the application folder should but i back slash first after require '/filename.php' or should i put double dots first?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is in the same directory, you could simply use: `include_once "db.php";`

If it is in parent directory(ie, one level up), then use:  `include_once "../db.php";`

Another one is to append the global DOCUMENT_ROOT with the filename(like others have given examples below).

And also, avoid mysql_* functions. Use PDO or mysqli instead.

Wish you good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question essentailly boils down to "how can I include a file that is in the root from anywhere". Well, there's two answers.

The first answer is to just use `inlude($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/connect.php");`, but that's a lot to type, especially if you have a lot of includes.

Personally, I like to start my script with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` Then I don't have to worry about where I am anymore - I will always be in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably it is not good that you open mysql connection on every `save`, if there will be many such calls per request.
2. `inlude($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/db.php');`

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:
First, if you don't need to use the password and username and database elsewhere, you should just define them in the function.

Second, If I'm not mistaken if you put the "/" in front of the path that will take you all the way down to the root of the filesystem, which I'm guessing this user wouldn't have access to.  That being said, I would use ".." to navigate up the hierarchy.  So use:
    require_once("../path/to/file.php")

Answer (score 0):

Rather that putting the include file in the document root, you should create a directory for common include files, and add it to the `include_path` setting in `php.ini`. Then you can just do `include 'connect.php';`.